# Unable to hit the breakpoints after attaching the Microsoft Word process while debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We have a C# application which communicates with Microsoft Word. We have recently migrated from Visual Studio 2008 to 2013. While debugging we have to attach the Word process in order to hit the break points. We are not able to hit the breakpoints even after attaching the Word process in VS 2013. Kindly help us on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your addin (in word) uses the same version as the one you have opened in VS 2013?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand your question. We are creating the addin in these projects, then launch Word and access the ribbons.

Comment: Is any ".exe" running for the word process in the backgroud? You can check in the task manager.

Comment: Yes.. Instance of WinWord.EXE is running in the background. We are able to attach the process. Just that we can't hit the breakpoints. We used to do the same on VS 2008 successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

1. Open Task Manager and try ending the process for any copy of WinWord.exe.
2. Open a Windows Explorer. Navigate to C:\Users\Local Settings..\AssemblyCache
3. If you don't see AssemblyCache, Organize > Folder and search options > View > uncheck "Hide protected operating system files (recommended)"
4. In the directories in AssemblyCache, look for the one containing your .dll.
5. Delete the .dll.
6. Rebuild the project and debug. Once your add in activates you should see the cache contents get refreshed.
7. If desired, re-hide the protected OS files.

I referred folowing link:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13606/why-cant-the-breakpoint-be-hit-when-debugging-an-arcgis-10-add-in

Not sure if this works for VS2013 too. Please try it out. All the best.